# mod_wgsi error with virtualenv and django

Tags: python, django

Im trying to deploy an django project  using wgsi/django1.5 and virtualenv
But Im getting the error,

```
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 mod_wsgi (pid=23927): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/project.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 230, in __call__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 40, in load_middleware
     mod = import_module(mw_module)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
     __import__(name)
   File "/opt/project/app1/middleware.py", line 2, in ?
     import requests
   File "/opt/pythonenv/django15/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58
      from . import utils
           ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which I think is down to the middleware being unable to import the requests module.

**wsgi**

```
import os
import sys

import site
site.addsitedir("/opt/pythonenv/django15/lib/python2.7/site-packages")

sys.path.append('/opt/')
sys.path.append('/opt/app1/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/opt/.python-eggs'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
        ServerName domain.com

        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/project/project.wsgi
        WSGIDaemonProcess domain.com processes=5 python-path=/opt/pythonenv/django15/bin/python threads=1
        Alias /media /project/app1/media
        Alias /admin_media /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media

</VirtualHost>
```

When im in my virtualenv I can import requests etc without any issues.

```
>>>
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
'1.5.1'
>>> import requests
>>>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What version of Python is your vitual environment using and what version of Python was mod_wsgi compiled against? And finally, which version of Python is mod_wsgi actually using (I don't see [any of the directives that you'd use for a virtualenv](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments) in your `httpd.conf`)

Comment: Python 2.7 is being used in my virtual environment, mod_wgsi im not sure as I wasnt the one that compiled it (how can i check).

Comment: Your best bet is probably `ldd mod_wsgi.so`.

Comment: ok so that comes back with 2.4. Is there no way of using a different version of python under this mod_wsgi ?

Comment: Have you tried with [WSGIPythonHome](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome) directive?  `WSGIPythonHome /your/path/to/python/2.7/exe/directory`